# Invalid signature detected in secure boot, how to fix?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, security, secure-boot

I'm getting "Invalid signature detected in secure boot".

All solutions that I've found says to disable secure boot in BIOS, which seem to be an insecure thing to want to do.

How can I have *valid* signature, not just ignore the warning message?

Answer (score 0):

I can’t add comment yet.
Was that booting before ? When the issue started ?
Looks like you need to update the keys at BIOS/UEFI level to get it fixed.